# Programa de adivinación de número aleatorio

Tags: php, java, html, base-de-datos

Programa que adivina un número aleatorio contra uno del usuario hasta que ambos coincidan.

```
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class Adivinando {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int numeroaleatorio1=(int)(Math.random()*100);
    int numero=0;
    int intentos=0;
    do{
        numero=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese Número"));
        if(numeroaleatorio1!=0){
            Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Ingrese numero"));
    while (numeroaleatorio1==numero);     
        }else if(numeroaleatorio1<numero){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ingrese Número mas bajo");
        }if(numeroaleatorio1>numero){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ingrese Número mas alto"); 
        }
        System.out.println ("Le atinaste con" + intentos +"intentos");
    //MARCA ERROR ME DICE QUE INSET WHILE (EXPESION)
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola @GOGO , Bienvenido a [StackOverflow en Español](https://es.stackoverflow.com), te recomiendo un [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) por la pagina para poder ganar tu primera medalla, y ver [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) para hacer un [ejemplo minimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) y la comunidad acepte de buena forma tu pregunta

Comment: Esto es php, java, html o base de datos? seguro no son los 4...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El juego es similar a cuando buscamos palabras en el diccionario, y se supone que lo más efectivo para ganar es aplicar el algoritmo de la búsqueda dicotómica, aunque cuando algo es aleatorio, nunca se sabe la cantidad de pasos que uno puede tardar.

Para resolver el código, usé un `for` en vez de un `while`, y además hice una función que pide el entero con el `JOptionPane`.

Para que los programas salgan bien y que se entiendan, hay que indentar bien el código (poner bien los tabuladores). De esta manera es más fácil saber dónde hay que poner el `while`. Recomiendo usar el [*IDE Eclipse*](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/).

Código resuelto:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Adivinando {

    public static int pedir(String mensaje)
    {
        return Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(mensaje));
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int numeroaleatorio1=(int)(Math.random()*100);
        int numero=0;
        numero=pedir("Ingrese Número: ");
        int intentos;
        for(intentos=0;numeroaleatorio1!=numero;intentos++)
        {
            if(numeroaleatorio1<numero){
                numero=pedir("Ingrese un número más bajo: ");
            }
            if(numeroaleatorio1>numero){
                numero=pedir("Ingrese un número más alto: ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println ("Le atinaste con " + intentos +" intentos.");
    }
}
```